# Source of ID on Google Admin user URL

Tags: python, admin, google-admin-sdk

I have an issue with getting a live list of users with two-step verification enabled from Google Admin using Admin-SDK.

The reporting API can be used to gather reports on who is currently enrolled, but these are not live, they are three days old. The directory API (users & groups) does not have this information.

What I am playing with now is scraping the google admin user page for enrollment status. **My question is what is the source of the ID on the google admin page?** It is not returned from the Directory API. Is it an encoded version of the userID?

[This is the ID I refer to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6Jrh.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have found that you can get an up to date list of users with 2FA enabled. By downloading a list of users from the Google Admin "Users" page.

Click the three dot symbol on the top right of the page and then select download users. Select the scope of the download and then you will have up-to-date documents on who is enrolled.

The reports feature of Google Admin is three days behind, which includes the reporting API. The users API has no way to pull 2FA enrollment, but the download users button lets you know any stragglers.

The reason I asked the question in the first place is because when you force two-step verification via the policy in the Security section, users who do not already have it enabled are locked out, as they are prompted for a two-step verification code which they are unable to acquire. You can create a 2FA exception group which allows them to log in and set it up, but then you must remove the users from the group who have it enabled; just for housekeeping purposes.

I cannot see a way to do this pragmatically using the admin-SDK without using the reporting API, which is three days behind and hence outdated. automated fashion. I'd love to see someone who has made it happen, so feel free to chime in!